# Javascript to generate new XHTML content not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I've been scratching at my head with this for a few days now and I cannot find any solution to this online or even with a professor.

I'm working on a system that requires some pages to be capable of dynamically generating new HTML content whilst running (JSF web project running on glassfish4 server)
I've found some resources on how to do this but it only worked when running on a standard HTML page. When I convert it to the XHTML standard the function no longer generates anything (although it is still being called, the alert box confirmed that).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        function addQuestion() {
            alert('yay');
            var exam = document.getElementById('divarea');
            var temp = document.createElementNS('h', 'button');
            temp.setAttribute('value', 'child');
            exam.appendChild(temp);
        }
    </SCRIPT>
    <div id="divarea">
    </div>
    <h:commandButton value="create new stuff" onclick="addQuestion()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can shed some light on this issue it'd be greatly appreciated.

P.S.
Here are the resources I've been using to attempt troubleshooting.

[Converting javascript to work with XHTML](http://javascript.about.com/od/hintsandtips/a/twodoms_2.htm)

[Creating elements dynamically using javascript](http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-and-remove-html-elements-dynamically-with-javascript/)

Comment: JSF+Facelets runs in server and produces HTML output based on XHTML source code and sends the HTML output to client (webbrowser). JavaScript runs in client and works on HTML DOM tree created based on HTML source retrieved from server. Think about this for a while until you get the adrenaline rush when you finally *really* understand something. This is web development 101. Also take the opportunity to put your mouse cursor on top of `[xhtml]` tag you placed below the question until a black info box shows up and then click therein the *info* link for more info.

Comment: Note: for the first parameter, you should specify the full namespace URI: `document.createElementNS('http://java.sun.com/jsf/html', 'button')`. You can find [good documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS). This won't help you with your problem here though, as BalusC stated.

Comment: Are you sure it's really XHTML now? XHTML is case sensitive, and your source therefore contains an unknown element, `<SCRIPT>`, which the browser wouldn't know how to handle. As a test, I saved your source as an .xhtml file, and it displayed the contents of the `<SCRIPT>` element on the screen rather than running the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"></meta>
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        </head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <body>
            <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
                function addQuestion() {


                    var oldcon=$("#divarea").html();
                    var newcon='<button>child</button>';
                    var updcon=oldcon+newcon
                    console.log(newcon);
                    $("#divarea").html(updcon);
                }
            </SCRIPT>
            <div id="divarea">
            </div>
            <button onclick="addQuestion()"/>dff</button>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this still did not work.